# google api 'Google_Service_Plus' : cannot access 'people get'

Tags: php, api, oauth

I can use google client to get the email, like this :

```
$this->client->setClientId('...');
$this->client->setClientSecret('...');
$this->client->setRedirectUri('...');
$this->client->setScopes('email');
$this->client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
$this->client->setDeveloperKey('...');
$this->client->setAccessType = 'offline';
```

...
    public function getEmail()
    {
        $this->setToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $this->client->verifyIdToken();
        $payload = $this->client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes()['payload']['email'];
        echo $payload;

...
This echoes the email. Good.

Now I want to use Google_Service_Plus 'people->get', like this :

```
$this->setToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
$this->client->verifyIdToken();
$googlePlus = new Google_Service_Plus($this->client);
$userProfile = $googlePlus->people->get('me');
```

But $userProfile returns this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=AIzaSyDvOsKSpSKmzVYV6m4tqZ5zHs8GIMdUv9s: (403) Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpacademy\googleauth\vendor\google\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 111
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

WOW!
I needed to activate the 'Google+ API' in https://console.developers.google.com.

Now it works!

Comment: I know it's obvious but you have to remember to activate a **server key** also on the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/faz-um-aue/apiui/credential#). I had only a browser key. Now it works